# Can you apply conditional logic to child elements with formkit?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, formkit

I am not quite sure I am understanding how this works or not.

I am using schema to build out an address auto complete setup.

I want to be able to show / hide the fields for manual input

This is what the form currently looks like
[image]

Initially, I want the section in blue to be hidden and only shown if `Can't find your address?` is checked

This is my code currently

```js
{
    $formkit: InputType.GROUP,
    name: 'address',
    label: label,
    children: [
      {
        $el: 'section',
        attrs: {
          class: 'mb-8 mt-8',
        },
        children: [
          {
            $el: 'h3',
            attrs: {
              class: `${labelClasses} mb-0`,
            },
            children: [label],
          },
          {
            $el: 'p',
            attrs: {
              class: 'text-sm font-normal mb-2',
            },
            children: [t('form.labels.address.help')],
          },
          {
            $formkit: InputType.ADDRESS_SEARCH,
            label: '',
            name: 'address',
            validation: 'required',
            classes: {
              outer: '!mb-2',
            },
          },
          {
            $formkit: InputType.CHECKBOX,
            label: t('form.labels.address.cant_find'),
            name: 'manual',
          },
          {
            $formkit: InputType.GROUP,
            name: 'address_details',
            label: 'address_details',
            children: [
              {
                $el: 'section',
                attrs: {
                  class: {
                    if: '$manual',
                    then: 'grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 ui-box py-5 px-4 mt-3 text-red-500',
                    else: 'grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 ui-box py-5 px-4 mt-3 text-blue-500',
                  },
                },
                children: [
                  {
                    $formkit: InputType.TEXT,
                    label: t('form.labels.street_address'),
                    name: 'street_address',
                    validation: 'required',
                    classes: {
                      outer: 'col-span-2 !mb-2',
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    $formkit: InputType.TEXT,
                    label: t('form.labels.city'),
                    name: 'city',
                    validation: 'required',
                    classes: {
                      outer: '!mb-2',
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    $formkit: InputType.TEXT,
                    label: t('form.labels.state'),
                    name: 'state',
                    validation: 'required',
                    classes: {
                      outer: '!mb-2',
                    },
                  },
                  {
                    $formkit: InputType.TEXT,
                    label: t('form.labels.country'),
                    name: 'country',
                    validation: 'required',
                    classes: {
                      outer: '!mb-2',
                    },
                  },
                  PostcodeSchema,
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
```

I am currently trailing by changing the text colour from blue to red based on the state of the `$manual` option

```js
attrs: {
   class: {
     if: '$manual',
     then: 'grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 ui-box py-5 px-4 mt-3 text-red-500',
     else: 'grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 ui-box py-5 px-4 mt-3 text-blue-500',
   },
},
```

However, it never seems to be changing the colour when selecting the manual option.
It is as if its not registering the change.

I am using [this playground example](https://formkit.com/playground?fkv=next&fileTab=Playground.vue&files=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&imports=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) which seems to do what I want, but is not working for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation and playing around [here](https://formkit.com/playground?fkv=next&fileTab=Playground.vue&files=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&imports=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), it turns out that you do need to supply the `v-model` and `data` attributes.

for me doing the following allowed it to start working

```
<template>
  <FormKit
    type="form"
    :actions="false"
    id="login"
    @submit="submit"
    v-model="data"
  >
    <FormKitSchema :schema="schema" :data="data" /> 
  </FormKit>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Schema } from './schema.ts'

const data = ref({
  address: {
    manual: false,
  },
});
</script>
```